# Issues with displaying a popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I am using the `Rg.Plugins.Popup` plugin for displaying a popup on a tap. My issue is how to call a popuppage from a viewmodel class? (I am using MVVM)

I am using the following code in viewmodel for the tap handler:

```
public async void OnForgotPasswordAsync()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new ForgotPassword());
        }
```

This is a `Command`

Here I have the view class for the popuppage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeHelp.View.ForgotPassword"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">

    <StackLayout Margin="12" Padding="24" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Please type your Email. Once you click on 'Send', please check your inbox or spam folder" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Email" Keyboard="Email"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Send" Command="{Binding SendPassword}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

So, my problem occurs at the command

```
 await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new ForgotPassword());
```

I get the error `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'WeHelp.View.ForgotPassword' to 'Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage'`

Comment: does ForgotPassword inherit from PopupPage in the codebehind class?

Comment: Partial declarations of 'ForgotPassword' must not specify different base classes

Comment: that doesn't answer my question - please post the class declaration for ForgotPassword

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? I tried to clean the solution but nothing happens also my class inherit from PopupPage

Comment: In my case, I just removed the character '&' which I wrote by mistake in `Text` of `Label` `<Label Text="&">`

Answer (score 0):

change your xaml to something like this

```
  <pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         xmlns:animations="clr-   
         namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class="HealthMobile.PopPages.ForgotPassowordPop">

</pages:PopupPage>
```

and page.cs to

```
public partial class ForgotPassowordPop : PopupPage
{
}
```